# Why close this question instead of editting it to make it on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Just read this question, [What kind of tools would I need to analyze 1000BASE-T/gigabit ethernet waveforms?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/99430/scope-recommendation-to-view-1000base-t-waveform), but was disappointed that it was marked as off-topic. I was interested in hearing what the experts had to say about it.

Someone suggested that a small change in title would make the question on-topic again. Well, I just did that, and am now waiting for the reviewers to approve it. I really hope they do.

So, my question is: **Why not edit the question to make it on-topic instead of voting to close it?** Is there a badge for closing questions that may be driving this behaviour? It's just too bad if there's pressure to get good questions like that off the site.

Comment: The edit was accepted. Now how do we reopen the question?

Comment: I went ahead and reopened it. Once it has been edited (after being closed) it gets put in the "reopen" queue for people to vote on reopening.

Comment: Mainly is a few people who feel personally offended that someone dare ask a question without thirty years experience and four degrees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you are encouraged to edit potentially good questions to turn them into *good* ones. Just, if you do so, leave a comment so that the poster can be aware of that and can improve the question.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I rarely edit questions to fix them.  I feel that if the OP can't write a proper question in the first place, then they don't belong here.

The rules for what is on topic, what belongs in a question (no *thank you* at the end), etc, are all spelled out.  Therefore, someone writing a bad question falls in one of two catagories:

Didn't bother read the rules.

Didn't bother following the rules.

Either way, it's not somebody that I want around.

Note that this is different from editing to fix simple errors, the occasional misspelling, awkward wording by someone not good with English but who otherwise seems to be genuinely trying, and removing a link by putting the schematic in line for someone who doesn't have enough rep to do it themselves.